# How to retrieve the applications icon at runtime that was set with .rc file on Windows or .icns file on Mac?

Tags: qt, icons

There's a method `QApplication::windowIcon()`, but it only works if you've set the icon with `setWindowIcon`. How to get the application icon that was set by specifying .rc or .icns file?

Comment: to be clear you want to fetch icon of application running your code! (probably you code is external library so you can't hard code that icon).

Comment: @MarekR: that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly try this:

```
QIcon programIcon() {
    QFileInfo fileInfo(qApp->arguments().at(0));

    return QFileIconProvider().icon(fileInfo);
}
```

See [QFileIconProvider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html).

If I misunderstood you then this should give you a clue, how to solve your problem.

Comment: Weird. It returns a non-null icon, but `availableSizes()` for that icon returns an empty list...

Comment: first try render it, and check Qt logs, maybe some warring reports what is the problem (it it doesn't render).

Comment: On mac this just loads a generic executable icon